# storing and receiving xml rss feed files

Tags: java, xml, drupal, rss

I have a Java back-end that produces updates from an input by user of the program. T
his gets saved to an XML file that is saved in the directory the server has access to.

So, from the program I can read the feed by setting the url as localhost/rssfile.xml.

However, when trying to pull the information and update the feed aggregator by using the same address. It wont let me connect.

I think it may be an address issue, however, I am unsure if this is a wise approach.

Comment: It would be easier to read this question if it used correct punctuation, spelling and grammar. What are you asking?

Comment: My Apologies. I have a Java back-end that produces updates from an input by user of the program. This gets saved to an XML file that is saved in the directory the server has access to. So, from the program I can read the feed by setting the url as http://localhost/rssfile.xml. However, when trying to pull the information and update the feed aggregator by using the same address. It wont let me connect.

Comment: resolved... needed to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost... sorry for the lame question. never done rss before

Comment: @clockworkworks - I suggest you edit your original question so that it's clearer and post your solution as an accepted answer to your own question. This may help you get rid of the negative rating on your question and help others who see it in future.

Comment: @nmc will do... I am new here as you can tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolved... needed to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.